# Unity Features not working after upgrade to 11.10

Tags: unity, 11.10, ati, graphics, radeon

I had purchased an HP Pavilion with the unsupported graphics card Radeon HD 6470M. I chose to not install the ATI proprietary drivers and simply work with the generic ones.

After my upgrade to 11.10 I noticed that after installing the ATI drivers (not the post-release ones, as apparently people have been having issues with Unity), my graphics card is working well. However, the Unity plugin was unchecked in Compiz. I have rechecked it but nothing has changed. No matter what I check or uncheck in compiz (like wobbly windows), there is no visual effect (these effects all worked with the generic drivers). Even my desktops are in the a straight line format and not in the 2x2 orientation, which gives problems when I press Super+S.

Is there something I need to do to activate Unity again? Should I reset it? Any other advice will be appreciated.

Comment: try log out and in after checking unity. Else try unity --replace if does not work try unity --reset

Comment: I tried the logout and still nothing. Before trying unity --replace and unity --reset, could I know what effect it will have? I've seen that unity --reset resets everything unity related. I'm not sure, however, if the issue I have is unity related.

Comment: unity --replace reloads unity with no changes in layouts but --resets resets the settings and launcher stuffs

Comment: I tried the unity --reset. It reset everything but still no effect. My Unity is not even checked, so before I checked it again, I wanted to know if there is anything else I can try first.

Comment: if all fails, try to purge and reinstall
sudo apt-get purge unity && sudo apt-get install unity

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try and pray that I still have Ubuntu when I'm done ;)

Comment: Just do not log off before you reinstall unity. Laternative will be installing Gnome shell if anything bad happen you  will have backup!

Answer (score 1):

You may be running Unity 2D - I would log out and click on the cog next to your password entry box, ensure you select Ubuntu as your desktop that way when you log in you will use Unity Shell if it has been enabled previously in CCSM.

It's a simple way to check before you try to purge then reinstall Unity......

Comment: I just checked and I have been running Ubuntu (not Unity 2D). Before I do a purge, should I have the option checked in Compiz? And will the reinstall put everything as it should? Will it affect the graphics card? (Sorry, I usually stick to defaults to avoid issues like this...